# Getting a Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true. On a overload type in my ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Here is the Property in the Base Class

```
[ReadOnly(true), Display(GroupName = "Payment Details")]
public virtual GridViewModel<PaymentDetails> Details { get; set; }
```

Here is the Property in the Inherited Class

```
[Display(AutoGenerateField = false, AutoGenerateFilter = false), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public override GridViewModel<PaymentDetails> Details { get; set; }
```

I get Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true. error Here is a piece of the  Call Stack

```
[InvalidOperationException: Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.]
   System.RuntimeType.get_DeclaringMethod() +9546416

[TargetInvocationException: Property accessor 'DeclaringMethod' on object 'System.RuntimeType' threw the following exception:'Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.']
   System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component) +400
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetPropertyValueAccessor>b__a() +18
   System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata.get_Model() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo.Visited(ModelMetadata metadata) +69
```

Comment: Please provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.